# No able to import ubuntu/trusty64

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am running on Windows 10 and using a VagrantFile, I up the Vagrant running using Administrator mode but am stuck at not able to import Ubuntu/trusty64.  Hope someone can advise me how to import it.

> C:\Users\Karen.Goh\VMLinux>vagrant up
>   Bringing machine 'default' up with 'hyperv' provider...
>   ==> default: Verifying Hyper-V is enabled...
>   ==> default: Verifying Hyper-V is accessible...
>   ==> default: Box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
>       default: Box Provider: hyperv
>       default: Box Version: >= 0
>   ==> default: Loading metadata for box 'ubuntu/trusty64'
>       default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/trusty64
>   The box you're attempting to add doesn't support the provider
>   you requested. Please find an alternate box or use an alternate
>   provider. Double-check your requested provider to verify you didn't
>   simply misspell it.

If you're adding a box from HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, make sure the box is
released.

Name: ubuntu/trusty64
Address: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/trusty64
Requested provider: [:hyperv]

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search,

[image]

that box is only available for VirtualBox. If you want Ubuntu for HyperV, use the right selection choices to check what is available:

[image]

Another solution is to install VirtualBox, that opens a lot more choices (never heard of HyperV as a VM support app, possibly Windows-only, which would restrict the audience).

Comment: Thanks.  I installed VirtualBox and disabled HyperV in Windows 10 and it is working now.

Comment: Upvoting is fine, but accepting is better (shows people that there is at least one valid answer to the question)(this is the `V` icon next to the votes for you).